# Manipulate object so that its own properties populate arrays inside the object itself

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects like this:

```
var array = [{
code : "1",
name : "code1",
parentCode : "0",
children : []
},{
code : "0",
name : "code0",
parentCode : "#",
children : []
}]
```

How can I push to the `children` arrays of the parent, the codes of the children? Ideally after the push, `array[1].children` should be `["1"]`

I have tried:

```
for (var i = 0; i<array.length;i++) {
    var parentArray = array.find(function(a){
         return a.parentCode == array[i].parentCode 
         });
parentArray.children.push(array[i].code);
}
```

And the results are scrambled. The children array contain a total mix of entries that make no sense (entries that originally do not belong there because their parent is different)

Should I do it differently?

Here is an example of the before/after that I want to accomplish:

**BEFORE:**

```
var array = [{
code : "0",
name : "code0",
parentCode : "#",
children : []
},{
code : "1",
name : "code1",
parentCode : "0",
children : []
},{
code : "2",
name : "code2",
parentCode : "0",
children : []
},{
code : "3",
name : "code3",
parentCode : "0",
children : []
},{
code : "4",
name : "code4",
parentCode : "1",
children : []
},{
code : "5",
name : "code5",
parentCode : "1",
children : []
}]
```

**AFTER (DESIRED RESULT):**

```
 var array = [{
code : "0",
name : "code0",
parentCode : "#",
children : ["1","2","3"]
},{
code : "1",
name : "code1",
parentCode : "0",
children : ["4","5"]
},{
code : "2",
name : "code2",
parentCode : "0",
children : []
},{
code : "3",
name : "code3",
parentCode : "0",
children : []
},{
code : "4",
name : "code4",
parentCode : "1",
children : []
},{
code : "5",
name : "code5",
parentCode : "1",
children : []
}]
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Can you provide both "before" (I think you've done that) and "after" examples of the desired structure, along with at least pseudo-code for the operation between them?

Comment: Ah...I got there in the end.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder But I added a longer example anyways just in case it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably do this in two passes (but see below):

1. Find all the parents and build a map of references to them by code
2. Find all the children, pushing them onto the parents

Something like this:

```js
// The data
var array = [{ code : "0", name : "code0", parentCode : "#", children : [] },{ code : "1", name : "code1", parentCode : "0", children : [] },{ code : "2", name : "code2", parentCode : "0", children : [] },{ code : "3", name : "code3", parentCode : "0", children : [] },{ code : "4", name : "code4", parentCode : "1", children : [] },{ code : "5", name : "code5", parentCode : "1", children : [] }];

// Build a mapping object of parents keyed by their codes
var map = Object.create(null);
array.forEach(function(entry) {
  map[entry.code] = entry;
});

// Push child codes into the parent `children` arrays
array.forEach(function(entry) {
  if (entry.parentCode != "#") {
    var parent = map[entry.parentCode];
    if (parent) {
      parent.children.push(entry.code);
    }
  }
});

// Show result
console.log(array);
```

The reason for doing it in two passes is to avoid unnecessary searching through `array`, looking for each parent. Looking up entries in a "mapping" object is much more efficient than finding entries in an array.

But if you want to do it in a single pass, your `find` approach would work too. The problem with your attempt is that you're comparing `parentCode` to `parentCode` (you should be comparing the child's `parentCode` with the child's `code`), and you haven't allowed for not finding the parent (maybe you know for sure they'll always exist):

```js
// The data
var array = [{ code : "0", name : "code0", parentCode : "#", children : [] },{ code : "1", name : "code1", parentCode : "0", children : [] },{ code : "2", name : "code2", parentCode : "0", children : [] },{ code : "3", name : "code3", parentCode : "0", children : [] },{ code : "4", name : "code4", parentCode : "1", children : [] },{ code : "5", name : "code5", parentCode : "1", children : [] }];

// Doing it in a single loop (but note that Array#find
// is also a loop, so this is less efficient than using
// a mapping object
array.forEach(function(child) {
  var parent = array.find(function(p) {
    return p.code == child.parentCode;
  });
  if (parent) {
    parent.children.push(child.code);
  }
});

// Show result
console.log(array);
```

---

Just for fun, here's the mapping version in ES2015+ (won't work on older browsers without transpilation):

```js
// The data
let array = [{ code : "0", name : "code0", parentCode : "#", children : [] },{ code : "1", name : "code1", parentCode : "0", children : [] },{ code : "2", name : "code2", parentCode : "0", children : [] },{ code : "3", name : "code3", parentCode : "0", children : [] },{ code : "4", name : "code4", parentCode : "1", children : [] },{ code : "5", name : "code5", parentCode : "1", children : [] }];

// Build a mapping object of parents keyed by their codes
let map = new Map();
array.forEach(entry => {
  map.set(entry.code, entry);
});

// Push child codes into the parent `children` arrays
array.forEach(entry => {
  if (entry.parentCode != "#") {
    let parent = map.get(entry.parentCode);
    if (parent) {
      parent.children.push(entry.code);
    }
  }
});

// Show result
console.log(array);
```

If you really wanted to be obscure, you could (ab)use `Array#reduce` for building the mapping object:

```
// Build a mapping object of parents keyed by their codes
let map = array.reduce((m, entry) => m.set(entry.code, entry), new Map());
```

Comment: It definitely works great. I was going to use your second option because it was closest to my initial work, but upon examination I think the first option makes more sense to me.